# Spring Data and MongoDB: Temporarily disable Optimistic Locking

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have used @EnableMongoAuditing in an application using Spring Data and MongoDB, to prevent concurrent modification on a Document by different users.

A part of the document is not editable by any users, but can be edited by the system itself (through a JMS message), using a MongoTemplate.

When the system updates that part of the document, however, it also increases he version number of the document, resulting in an optimistic locking exception.

Of course I don't want this to occur. The change in the document by the JMS message is just a String in one of the document's children changing, and never related to a change one of the users is able to do.

How can I prevent this happening? For example by (very temporarily) disabling the version increase and validation.